# How do I persist a high speed stream of positional information

Tags: database, postgresql, stream, bigdata, throughput

I'm receiving a high speed stream (up to 14 Mbps) of positional information (let's simplify this to (x, y, z, timestamp).

After storing this data, I perform operations such as retrieving points within a bounded 3D space, retrieving points within a timeframe, etc.

I've tried PostgreSQL + PostGIS with sharding by timeframe, but the database can't handle the load. A query for all points within the past hour takes more than 10 minutes.

I have one server (IIRC 8 quad core 2.0GHz CPUs, 32GB RAM). What solutions / technologies / techniques can I use to persist and query the data quickly?

If I had more than one server, what solutions would be ideal?

Thanks!

Comment: If by "sharding" you mean partition then show how you did it with a minimum of a schema.

Comment: I'm partitioning the database table by day, so I have 1 table each of (x,y,z,t) for each day e.g. table(20140214), table(20140213), etc etc.

Comment: 14 Mbps is a lot. I guess you can't do much beyond checking the configuration and partition by hour.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [TSDB](http://opentsdb.net), if you haven't already done so. It was developed for a use case very similar to what you have described above.